# Detect unbound native functions like `Array.push`?

Tags: javascript

Observe the following:

```
function array_map(array, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        callback(array[i]);
    }
}
var a = [], b = [];

array_map([1, 2, 3], function (x) { a.push(x); });
// just gives a = [1, 2, 3] as expected

// but why does this not work: ?
array_map([1, 2, 3], b.push);
// Chrome: a = [], Firefox: can't convert undefined to object
```

I **do** understand why this happens, namely: `push` is no longer bound to `b` (but to the global object) if you pass it to `array_map` directly. I don't really understand why Chrome doesn't give an error, at least Firefox seems to give some kind of error.

**How can I detect if a function like this is passed to `array_map` to avoid these kinds of *bugs*?**

I'm hoping there are advanced reflection techniques available to trace the origin of a function. For instance `b.push.constructor` gives `Function`, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can't. You can control it using `bind` when you're calling the function, but inside the function, you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I'm not sure what you expect there to happen. `Array.prototype.map` requires a function as second parameter, which returns a **new** value for every iteration.</strike>

Passing in just a function reference (which you do in your second example) doesn't tell the function what it has to do anyway. So you're kinda expecting that `.map()` applies some black magic and calls the passed in method with the correct parameter, which it obviously, can't do.

I totally didn't get that you wrote your own mapping function. However, your problem there is that you're losing *scope* of that `.push()` function. Only if you call it on the `Array / Object` like `xxx.push()`, the `this` within the called function will correctly reference the target object. Once you just passed the reference, `this` will either point to *global* / `window` or `undefined` and won't work anymore.

So solve that issue you could call it like

```
array_map([1, 2, 3], b.push.bind(b));
```

which also would apply an ES5 function. You can't really detect for it within the `array_map()`. A function is a function, your best shot would be to detect whether or not the passed in method is a native or not, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: He's using `[].push`, not `map`.

Comment: I understand that there are workarounds to avoid this, like using `bind` or a _closure_. But this code passes unattested in Chrome, if there is any easy way to catch it: I would like to.

Comment: You mean: do a string conversion on the function and check for the occurance of "native code"? I agree that it's not a good idea ..

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Pretty much that and no, that's not a good idea. Anyway, I don't think its a good idea in general to check for that kind of stuff within that `array.map` function. Its totally the wrong place. Actually, there shouldn't be any check.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that Javascript has no such thing like "methods" - a function exclusively bound to a certain object. In your first example you pass a function which invokes `a.push`.  `this` is bound to `a` here because you invoke it directly on a.

In your second code you just pass the function `push` without the context of `b` - `this` will be bound to the execution context which is the gloabl object.

You need to bind the the context of the function like the following:

```
array_map([1, 2, 3], b.push.bind(b));
```

or jQuery's `proxy()`. I can't find another simple solution at the moment but the one to hand over the context directly in a third parameter: `function array_map(array, callback, context)`

Answer (score 1):

Usually these sorts of functions would allow you to set the context of the callback.

If you change your array_map function to accept a context, then it will work like this.

```
function array_map(array, callback, context) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        callback.call(context, array[i]);
    }
}
var b = [];

// now the push method is called from the b context
array_map([1, 2, 3], b.push, b);
```